# Issue iterating through an object via Ajax call in C# MVC Framework

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I am having issues iterating through the Object returned by the controller in C# MVC framework in my AJAX script.

Ajax script:

```
function getRName(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resourceNamePopup',
        method: 'post',
        data: { "search": obj.value },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            $.each(data.items, function (items) {
                alert(items.displayName);
            });

        }
    });
}
```

C# Action:

```
    public ActionResult resourceNamePopup(string search)
    {
        List<ResourceName> rnList = new List<ResourceName>();
        rnList = getResourceName(search);

        return Json(rnList );
    }
```

I get this error now

> Unhandled exception at line 645, column 4 in http://localhost:52273/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Why are you returning `List<object>`? Just return `rnList` instead.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I corrected it. Now I get this error:                  
       
Unhandled exception at line 645, column 4 in http://localhost:52273/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: You need to [edit] the question to provide additional details, do not provide them as comments. There is an [edit] link directly under your question that you should use.

Comment: what error do u have faced?

Answer (score 0):

The `obj` seems a pointless wrapper round what is just a single list. You only ever add one item to `obj`, so it doesn't really do anything useful to have that as a list. just return the `rnList` directly instead. And then in the JS just loop directly over `data`. Also the fact you return a list of Object, which has no properties, means none of your properties get serialised into JSON, because it uses the type of the object being serialised to decide what to include in the JSON.

This should work better, and is simpler:

C#

```
public ActionResult resourceNamePopup(string search)
{
    List<ResourceName> rnList = getResourceName(search);
    return Json(rnList);
}
```

JS

```
function getRName(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resourceNamePopup',
        method: 'post',
        data: { "search": obj.value },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            if (data != null || data.length == 0) {
              $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                alert(item.displayName);
              });
            }
            else { alert("No results"); }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake. I corrected it. Now I get this error: Unhandled exception at line 645, column 4 in localhost:52273/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @anand Did you modified `$.each(data, function (items) {` part too?

Comment: @anand Actually I think you got the definition of the callback to `.each` wrong - the first argument is the index (just a number), not the current object. See the correction I just made, also see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ for details . You should also check whether `data` is populated before trying to loop - if the result set was empty you can't loop it.

Comment: Thank you! you guys are awesome.  I am able to iterate the object.

Comment: @anand no problem. In that case please mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out two problems

1. You don't need to add into `List<object>`
2. `$.each(data.items, function (items)` part is not correct

You need to return `rnList` instead (from method `resourceNamePopup()` **[Also please make method and property names start with uppercase]**).

and inside AJAX response use this:

```
function getRName(obj) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resourceNamePopup',
        method: 'post',
        data: { "search": obj.value },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            $.each(data, function (i) {
                alert(data[i].displayName);
            });

        }
    });
}
```